# iOS How to make UIButton below UICollectionView receive touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have next structure

```
UView -
      - UIView2 with Button
      - CollectionView - which overlap UIView2 and has contentInset
```

[image]

I can't make to Button receive touch events.

I try pointInside with check clear color (collectionView has backgroundColor is set to clear color)

But i need to scroll work event on blue part (UIView2)

So, i need then i touch collectionView touch also receive a UIButton

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your collection view need to overlap the button? Anyway, you can try overriding HitTest in UIView like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pointInUIView2 = [UIView2 convertPoint:point fromView:self];

    if ([UIView2 pointInside:pointInUIView2 withEvent:event])
    {
        return UIView2;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
}
```