# iOS how to make collectionView receive touches if it's below some uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I ask some different scenario:

[iOS How to make UIButton below UICollectionView receive touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702990/ios-how-to-make-uibutton-below-uicollectionview-receive-touch)

But also i wonder is it possible align collectionView below uiview with no transparent backgroundColor and make to receive touches?

[image]

I want then i move finger at blue view trigger collectionView scroll behavior AND also i want to UIButton receive touches.

Hit test not a solution.

Why?

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        for (UIView *subview in [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
            CGPoint convertedPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *hitTestView = [subview hitTest:convertedPoint withEvent:event];
            if (hitTestView) {
                return hitTestView;
            }
        }
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Just because it's not fired when finger at blue view.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UIView (blue) with userInteractionEnabled=YES then use this `hitTest`:

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) return nil; // <--- pass-through if touch on UIView (blue view)
    else return hitView; // touch on children (UIButton)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not a solution for me. Because blue view it's just a container. Which will include a ImageView for example or even collectionView (for scroll photos).